# first row in my pointer array printing is broken and not sure why

Tags: arrays, c, database, pointers, printing

Basically trying to print from a data file using a structure. Not sure why but the output for the first row goes crazy. Also, yes i know theres huge mem leak right now I need to do stuff with the data before i can purge it

CSCE1040
�U, PU: -1214516224, 21942, -1214517008
Cummings, Kelley: 74, 70, 79
Reynolds, Jamie: 64, 52, 66
...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "student.h"
#include "bubble.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

student ***studentDataBase;

struct classStats
{
  char* name;
  float mean;
  float min;
  float max;
  float median;
};

void printStudent(student *studentData) //print student data
{
printf("%s, %s: %d, %d, %d\n", 
        studentData->last,
        studentData->first,
        studentData->exam1,
        studentData->exam2,
        studentData->exam3);
}

void printData(student *students[], int studentcount) 
//for each student call printStudent
{
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<studentcount;i++)
      printStudent(students[i]);
}

int main()
{
  int studentcount = 19;
  //classStats classStats;
  char className[10];
  char tempFirst[50];
  char tempLast[50];

  scanf("%s", className); 
//get and print class name to skip first line
  printf("%10s\n", className);

  studentDataBase = (student***) malloc (studentcount*sizeof(student**)); 
//allocate mem for #students rows
  for(int i=0; i<studentcount;i++)
  {
    studentDataBase[i] = (student**) malloc(6*sizeof(student*));
//allocate mem for 6 columns
    for(int j=0;j<6;j++)
    studentDataBase[i][j] = NULL;
  }

  for(int i=0;i<studentcount;i++) 

  {
    studentDataBase[0][i] = (student*)malloc(sizeof(student));
//allocate mem for data in each column
    scanf("%s %s %d %d %d" //fill in student data
          ,tempFirst, tempLast
          ,&studentDataBase[0][i]->exam1, &studentDataBase[0][i]->exam2, 
&studentDataBase[0][i]->exam3);
    //allocate space for student name
    studentDataBase[0][i]->first = (char*)malloc(strlen(tempFirst)+1); //allocate mem for 
char array
    strcpy(studentDataBase[0][i]->first, tempFirst);
    studentDataBase[0][i]->last = (char*)malloc(strlen(tempLast)+1);
    strcpy(studentDataBase[0][i]->last, tempLast);

    for(int j=1;j<studentcount;j++)
//copy current student data to all student data
    studentDataBase[j][i] = studentDataBase[0][i];
  }

  printData(*studentDataBase,studentcount);

  free(studentDataBase);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not enough information given to compile or enter data. Re: `studentDataBase[0][i] = (student*)malloc(sizeof(student));` you overwrite the previous memory allocation. Worse is the first time you had 6 columns and now 19 students. I suggest a bit of debugging is needed.

Comment: Why all the complexity? Pointers to pointers to pointers and a struct (not shown)? Just read a line and print its contents. If, as suggested in the code, you need to calculate statistics, then sum what needs summing and count what needs counting and track min/max, but do it all on the fly.... Don't build a Rube Goldberg device... KISS!

Comment: input is a database and i need to be able to access each student individually which is predefined using malloc and pointers. and also access the whole database for calculation so pointer pointer pointer. project for class

Answer (score 0):

Mistake in the end,

```
 for(int j=1;j<studentcount;j++)
//copy current student data to all student data
    studentDataBase[j][i] = studentDataBase[0][i];
```

I was copying over the 19 pointers to the array which houses 6 pointers.

```
for(int j=1;j<6;j++)
    //copy current student data to all student data
        studentDataBase[j][i] = studentDataBase[0][i];
```

Should look like this because basically in my code, 'i' represents the rows of data, and 'j' represents the columns of data.